# Creating a weekend dummy variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a dummy variable in my dataset in R for weekend i.e. the column has a value of 1 when the day is during a weekend and a value of 0 when the day is during the week.

I first tried iterating through the entire dataset by row and assigning the weekend variable a 1 if the date is on the weekend. But this takes forever considering there are ~70,000 rows and I know there is a much simpler way, I just can't figure it out.

Below is what I want the dataframe to look like. Right now it looks like this except for the weekend column. I don't know if this changes anything, but right now date is a factor. I also have a list of the dates fall on weekends:

```
weekend <- c("2/9/2013", "2/10/2013", "2/16/2013", "2/17/2013", ... , "3/2/2013")

date          hour          weekend
2/10/2013     0             1
2/11/2013     1             0
....          ....          ....
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: R has built-in knowledge of weekdays and weekends. You don't have to keep a vector of weekend date strings. For instance, `transform(DF, weekend=as.POSIXlt(date, format='%m/%d/%Y')$wday %in% c(0, 6))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DF$IsWeekend <- DF$date %in% weekend
```

Then if you really prefer 0s and 1s:

```
DF$IsWeekend <- as.numeric(DF$IsWeeekend)
```

Answer (score 5):

It might be safer to rely on data structures and functions that are actually built around dates:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "date          hour          weekend
+ 2/10/2013     0             1
+ 2/11/2013     1             0",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> weekdays(as.Date(as.character(dat$date),"%m/%d/%Y")) %in% c('Sunday','Saturday')
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

This is essentially the same idea as SenorO's answer, but we convert the dates to an actual date column and then simply use `weekdays`, which means we don't need to have a list of weekends already on hand.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if my dates are really weekend dates before.

```
weekends <- c("2/9/2013", "2/10/2013", "2/16/2013", "2/17/2013","3/2/2013")
weekends = weekends[ as.POSIXlt(as.Date(weekends,'%m/%d/%Y'))$wday %in% c(0,6)]
```

Then using `trsanform` and `ifelse` I create the new column

```
transform(dat ,weekend = ifelse(date %in% as.Date(weekends,'%m/%d/%Y') ,1,0 ))
```